# Does Mobile View in Chrome-Dev-Tools force scaling?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

It seems to me that Chrome (in contrast to for example Firefox) automatically scales down certain html-content when using the developer tools' mobile view:

Take this minimal example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html {
                height: 100%;
            }
            body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 40px;
            }
            .test {
                background-color: lime;
                height: 100px;
                padding: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="test">Test Test Test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For me, when going into mobile view, the green divs' size and font-size is scaled relatively to the window width. However, I would expect it to have a constant height of `100px`. In normal view, everything is as expected, no scaling.

I have recorded this behavior in this gif:
[Chrome Resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QcaX.gif)

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of css or is this a special behavior by Chrome? How should I create divs of constant height, so I can work with them in Chrome? Thank you!

Comment: Try to add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> in your <head>.
You can read this article to understand the diffrence between CSS Resolution and Device Resolution:
https://medium.com/@elad/understanding-the-difference-between-css-resolution-and-device-resolution-28acae23da0b

Comment: Thank you @Liveindream ! The `<meta>` tag you posted was exactly what I was looking for. I expected this to be the default behavior, but I now understand that the down-scaling makes sense to have a chance to render non-responsive old websites. I can't mark your comment as accepted answer, can I?

Comment: I think it's not implemented by design, you can upvote a comment or add your own answer with all the details, for more info https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1558 @Raphael

Comment: Okay, I have added an own answer (need to wait until tomorrow to accept it). Unfortunately I can't upvote your comment since I need 15 reputation. Thank you again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comment by @Liveindream solved my issue:

> Try to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to your `<head>`.

That way, browsers are prevented from applying scaling to the page. The scaling is a browser strategy to fit non-responsive old websites into a smartphone screen. Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).